# Drupal - Change From address for email to user awaiting administrator approval?

Tags: drupal

Users awaiting administrator approval are sent an email from the site's default email address. Is it possible to change the from address for these emails only?
Thanks

UPDATE - Nevermind, instead Ive changed the site email and used the User Registration Notification module to send alerts to a different email.

Comment: You should either add your "update" as answer to your own question, for future reference. Else it will be closed.

Comment: I tried to answer my question but the site said i couldnt do it for 48 hours and to edit my answer in the mean time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, instead Ive changed the site email and used the User Registration Notification module to send alerts to a different email.